# Click Once Deployment - How to publish an application which has multiple VS projects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I'm building a complex WPF application. I'm having multiple visual studio solutions. Each solution has a project. Due to code protection reason, I had to place projects in separate solutions.

1. ComponentMain Solution (WPF Application)
2. ComponentA Solution (Class Library)
3. ComponentB Solution (Class Library)

Component A & B referenses assembly of Main Solution. The main solution loads the assemblies of Component A & B using reflection during the runtime.

When I build each solution, an Xcopy post build event will be triggered and all the dll's are copied  into a folder called GlobalOutput, where I can run the application by simply running the MainSolution.exe.

Now I want to publish the application using ClickOnce. As I mentioned earlier, there are multiple projects and Dll's are loaded using reflection.

As per to my knowledge I cannot use the click once publish wizard due to above reason. May be i'm wrong.

How can I publish my application using click once.?
As I haveing all the dll's in GlobalOutput directory, Is there any way to create clickkonce deployment directly from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify which files are published by Click Once.

For you, it will be something like:

- Pick one of those solutions/projects as the publishing project to configure Click Once. You need to mark the dlls from the other projects/solutions as prerequisites.

  1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
  2. Click the Publish tab.
  3. Click the Application Files button to open the Application Files dialog box.
  4. In the Application Files dialog box, select the application assembly (.dll file) that you wish to mark as a prerequisite. Note that your application must have a reference to the application assembly in order for it to appear in the list.
  5. In the Publish Status field, select Prerequisite from the drop-down list.

To make the file from the other solutions/projects appear in the Application File Dialog box in step 3, you can either reference the output dlls, or add them as solution file and set the build action to content.

For more information: [Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-specify-which-files-are-published-by-clickonce)

Comment: your comment says: "Note that your application must have a reference to the application assembly in order for it to appear in the list." But how can i include non referenced dlls?

Comment: You can either reference the dlls, or  go to the project you want to publish as click once, add existing items, add the existing dlls. Verify that the dll item has Build Action set to content.